# Optimal RESTful method for web service

Tags: android, web-services, rest

I'm looking for guidance on the optimal REST/Json method to use for our production app.  The scenario is app <-> web service <-> server (lighttpd or nginx) <-> our program <-> sql database.  The data traffic between Android and server per call is pretty small.  There is no significant CRUD on the client.

I've seen the Google IO 2010 presentation (http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-developing-RESTful-android-apps.pdf) with the 3 proposed patterns (Service API, ContentProvider API, ContentProvider API and a SyncAdapter).  Have briefly looked at the iosched 2010/11 app though haven't worked out which of the 3 methods (if any) it implements.

We want to offer our app users a seamless experience by managing state to support various types of interruption or failure.  How can we determine what is the optimal REST method for our need?  Are the Google suggestions overkill?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer depends on how much data and what operations we are talking about.

You wrote: "There is no significant CRUD on the client." If you are only using the "R" from "CRUD" (=read data from somewhere), AND if your app doesn't really depend on it, AND you are not synchronizing content frequently, you may even get away with fetching it form inside your Activities.

However you may want to explore the Service API from the get-go anyway. Like that Google presentation said, your Activity can be shut down at any time, so if makes sense to put your REST methods somewhere where they have a better chance of completing.

Please consider the future needs of your app, its use cases, and then look at the available options.